# Убрать ограничение в отзывах

Tags: opencart

Увеличение количества символов в отзывах в _OpenCart Version 2.1.0.1 (rs.2). По умолчанию стоит 1000 максимум. Что нужно сделать, чтоб увеличить количество?

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите файл `/catalog/controller/product/product.php` , а точнее функцию `public function write()`.
Так получается текст отзыва:

```
if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['text']) < 25) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['text']) > 1000)) {
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_text');
            }
```

Если текст меньше 25 символов или больше 1000, то получаем ошибку.

Comment: Изменял значение тут на 10000, а мне все равно пишит что максимум 1000 и не отправляет комент.

Comment: Системный кэш и кэш модификаторов чистили? Ни что из `ocmod` на отзывы не влияет?

Comment: Да чистил не помогает ocmod не установлен, vqmod установлен.

Comment: Чуть ли не первым делом на OC магазинах меняю минимальную длину символов в тексте отзыва таким образом. И разрешаю оценку товара без отзыва. `ocmod` идет в "двойке" из коробки, `vqmod` ,имхо, в двойке, это зло. Надо чистить кэш модификаторов. Для проверки, можно контроллере, где правку делали, ошибку сделать, например `;` потерять и посмотреть, упадет страница или нет. Если нет, значит где-то кэшируется.

Comment: Еще, как вариант, в шаблоне автор темы мог проверку сделать. Тема какая, дефолт?

Comment: Помогло для продуктов отключить, но исполнитель доделывал модуль новостей для отдельной страницы и для нее не работает эта манипуляция(( Спасибо.

Comment: Да Он в модификаторы закинул все проверки, разобрался спасибо.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.